# cmd.exe throws error "& was unexpected at this time."

Tags: powershell, unity-game-engine, batch-file, cmd

so my problem is that when **i just ran cmd.exe in terminal, i get "& was unexpected at this time."** Error at the end - looks like this

[image]

So the problem is that i'm getting erros in Unity 3D when it wants to run the unity_csc.bat file and compile solution. These errors are exactly the same as the one when i just run cmd.exe - therefore i suspect its not an Unity3D based problem (if you want you can check the Unity3D specific thread here https://forum.unity.com/threads/2-empty-errors-in-console-was-unexpected-at-this-time.799110/ )

Does anyone know why this might be happening ? This also happens when i try to run a .bat file - which I suspect is why i cant compile Unity project

[image]

I'm running Windows 10 with all of the latest updates

**EDIT:**

Since cmd /d does not throw the error, might there be some problem with this registry record ? [image]

In User Folder i do have this Autorun record

```
@mode 20,5 & tasklist /FI "IMAGENAME eq SoundMixer.exe" 2>NUL | find /I /N "SoundMixer.exe">NUL && exit & if exist " ( start /MIN "" " & tasklist /FI "IMAGENAME eq explorer.exe" 2>NUL | find /I /N "explorer.exe">NUL && exit & explorer.exe & exit ) else ( tasklist /FI "IMAGENAME eq explorer.exe" 2>NUL | find /I /N "explorer.exe">NUL && exit & explorer.exe & exit )
```

[image]

Comment: Is it the same issue when you try `cmd.exe /d`?

Comment: Hi Stephan, nope - cmd.exe /d gives just Windows info and no error

Comment: fine. `/d` deactivates autorun of some commands in the registry. Probably you have a problem there. `cmd /?` tells you the registry-keys to check.

Comment: Thanks Stephan for the pointers ! I'm not entirely sure if this was the right thing to check or what to do with it, but it looks like i'm either missing Autorun folder or Autorun registry entry - I've updated my question with more info

Comment: The string in your Autorun record is strange/wrong in so many ways - do you happen to know, where it comes from? I personally would just delete it (default is no entry)

Comment: Yep i agree - Actually, last few weeks when i start my PC my explorer.exe does not come up so i have to run it manualy through Task Manager :D I think this might be the cause of that issue. I'll remove it, let you know and accept the answer. Thanks !

Comment: Don't bother - your question is off-topic for this site anyway (not code-related). Better delete it before downvoting starts. Glad I could help. Merry Christmas!

Answer (score 26, accepted):

[Stephan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2152082/stephan) has provided the crucial pointer:

It sounds like **you have a broken *autorun* command defined for `cmd.exe`**; that is, your registry defines a command that is automatically executed whenever you call `cmd.exe`, and that command causes the syntax error you're seeing.

Note that such commands are executed irrespective of whether you open an interactive `cmd` session or invoke via a batch file or pass a command to `cmd` with `/C`.

Passing `/D` to `cmd` bypasses any autorun commands.

There are ***two* locations in the registry** where such a command can be defined, one at the local-machine level (which applies to all users), 
`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor`, and another for the current user only, 
`HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor`, in a value named `AutoRun`.
If commands are defined in *both* locations, the `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE`'s commands run first.

To **list** any defined autorun commands:

```
Get-ItemProperty -ea Ignore ('HKCU:', 'HKLM:' -replace '$', '\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor') AutoRun
```

You can use the following PowerShell snippet to **remove** autorun commands from both locations, but note that you'll have to run it *with elevation* (as administrator), if a local-machine value is present:

```
Get-ItemProperty -ea Ignore ('HKCU:', 'HKLM:' -replace '$', '\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor') AutoRun |
  Remove-ItemProperty -Name AutoRun -WhatIf
```

<sup>Note: The [**`-WhatIf`** common parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_commonparameters#-whatif) in the command above ***previews* the operation**. Remove `-WhatIf` and re-execute once you're sure the operation will do what you want.

Also note the unfortunate need to *repeat* the value name (`AutoRun`) in the `Remove-ItemProperty` call, because only the item path (registry key path), not also the property name (registry value name) can be bound via the pipeline.</sup>

Comment: Thanks a lot, you saved my day! I got this error because I had a "&" symbol in my autorun, due to a Conda install error.

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/66901281