# The "conda init" command is messing up my cmd startup in Win10

Tags: anaconda, window, regedit

## What happened

I re-installed the anaconda on the good shinning day.

After installation, I run

```
conda init
```

to startup the conda environment.

Then, I found everything in my build is messed up.
The cmd always complain about there are not supposed to be a "&" symbol.
As a result, all the commands using the cmd is dead.

Finally, I find out the reason is the conda has changed the regedit key of

> HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor\AutoRun

into

> if exist & if exist

It is definitely wrong.
After delete the bug string.
Everything is just fine.

## My Mistake

I admit I was wrong to run the command, the correct command should be

```
conda init powershell
```

or

```
conda init cmd.exe
```

to install the anaconda environment in Win10.

## My Question

My question is in two folders,

1. Why the anaconda messes my regedit key like that?
2. Why can't I reproduce the bug after that?

Can anyone help?

## My Advice

If your cmd is broken too in the future, you can check the regedit for a quick debug.

Comment: `conda init --help` says "shells             One or more shells to be initialized. If not given, the default value is 'bash' on unix and 'cmd.exe' on Windows."

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to fix this by running `conda init --reverse` in each shell.

In the event the AutoRun command sticks areound, you can remove it following the steps listed here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/59481892

Answer (score 0):

The related code is here
https://github.com/conda/conda/blob/6f76e4ccb38e23ffce079e63e2abcff051da9176/conda/core/initialize.py#L1414-L1473

But I don't know How it change `AutoRun` to `if exist & if exist`