# Reinstalling anaconda causes command prompt to break

Tags: windows, powershell, cmd, anaconda, conda

This issue boggled my mind! I uninstalled and reinstalled anaconda today because the activate environment command caused an error every time it was run.

Hoping to make progress, things rather went the other direction. Command line closes immediately after opening (too fast to see), and on powershell I get the following error without having written any command:

[image]

Running any conda command brings back the same error. I've searched but I'm a bit stuck, given that it's a fresh install. I can't run `conda install anaconda-clean` because it fails with the same error.

Comment: Maybe there's something in one of Powershell [profiles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_profiles?view=powershell-7.2)?

Comment: Anaconda is really badly designed, and decides to automatically run commands every time you open your built-in Prompt windows. It should be very easy for you to search this site or your chosen search providers pages, to find out where it places those commands, and remove/replace them.

Comment: EDIT: A solution after months of pain! Just open powershell and run `Reg Delete "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor" /v AutoRun /f `. Credit to this superuser post: https://superuser.com/questions/1628947/cmd-crashes-with-exit-code-1-after-uninstalling-anaconda

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/66901281