# In VsCode, how to change the default path to run to activate venv in new terminals?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, python-venv

I am running Visual Studio Code in windows 10 environment.

I am trying to set up VsCode to activate venv when I create a new terminal or I open VsCode.

Here is some settings in `.vscode/settings.json`

```
    "python.pythonPath": "venv\\Scripts\\python.exe",
    "python.defaultInterpreterPath": "venv\\Scripts\\python.exe",
    "python.terminal.activateEnvironment": true,
    "python.terminal.activateEnvInCurrentTerminal": true,
```

The problem is it runs

```
c:/abs/path/to/project/venv/Scripts/Activate.ps1
```

that returns

```
& was unexpected at this time.
```

instead of

```
c:/abs/path/to/project/venv/Scripts/Activate
```

that activates the virtual environment

I am using company laptop with limited access so I can not [have access to registry and fix it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59480657/cmd-exe-throws-error-was-unexpected-at-this-time).

So, the question is, **how to make VsCode use**

```
c:\abs\path\to\project\venv\Scripts\Activate
```

Note: if I run `c:/abs/path/to/project/venv/Scripts/Activate` it activates venv for me

Answer (score 0):

Is the `venv` a `conda` environment? **If so**, please note:

> Note: conda environments cannot be automatically activated in the integrated terminal if PowerShell is set as the integrated shell. See Integrated terminal - Configuration for how to change the shell.

Source: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments

You'll need to set your default integrated terminal to use command prompt -- please see:
https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/integrated-terminal#_terminal-profiles

E.g., add/replace this in your settings.json:

```
"terminal.integrated.defaultProfile.windows": "Command Prompt",
...
```